# Why work is not defined as the ratio of force and displacement? And why work is not defined as the distance in the direction of force?

Tags: forces, vectors, weak-interaction

Why work is not defined as the ratio of force and displacement? And why work is not defined as the distance in the direction of force? I see work is calculated as W=(F\cos \alpha)s$. but why not $W=(s \cos \alpha)F$ ? I know the answer will same as work is a scalar and we do dot product but the definition is about the projection of force.

Comment: W = F + s wouldn't be dimensionally consistent. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question as W = (F cosθ) S is the same as W = (S cosθ) F. We could say it was force times the component of distance in the direction of the force and we'd get the same result. I guess it's just easier for students to visualise the component of the force.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Your "comment" is really an answer?

Comment: @Farcher I'm not sure what the OP is asking. I'd prefer for them to clarify their question based on my comment before posting an answer.

Comment: @john Rennie, Sorry now i have eddited and the second part means actually, we read in books work is defined the projection of the force on displacement times displacement. but why we do not define as projection of displacement on force times force?

Comment: What's the difference? Work is generally as defined as $W=\vec F\cdot \vec r=|F|\cos\theta|r|=|F||r|cos\theta$. You can use the projection of the force on the displacement or the projection of the displacement on the force. Ultimately, work depends on the magnitudes of the force and displacement and also the degree to which they are aligned.